# Where binary in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL statement:

`SELECT * FROM customers WHERE BINARY login='xxx' AND password='yyyy'`

There are no blob/binary fields in the table, do I need the BINARY after the WHERE what else does it do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[**`BINARY`**](http://gilfster.blogspot.com/2005/08/case-sensitivity-in-mysql.html) is a built-in keyword that after your `WHERE` clause that forces a comparison for an *exact* case-sensitive match.

As a side note, you can also make columns case-sensitive by adding the `BINARY` keyword when you create your table.

Comment: This could be clearer. It implies that the BINARY key word after WHERE is a flag that makes the search case-sensitive, which is somewhat misleading. As DVK points out the BINARY key word *casts* the string following it to a binary string. Case-sensitivity is a side-effect of that cast and it only affects that one word. The BINARY has to be repeated in every AND or OR clauses if you want them to also be case-sensitive. Binary can also be used in SELECT statements.

Comment: this answer saved my day even 11 years on

Answer (score 9):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary

The BINARY operator casts the string following it to a binary string. This is an easy way to force a comparison to be done byte by byte rather than character by character. BINARY  also causes trailing spaces to be significant.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT 'user' = 'UsEr' // true
SELECT BINARY 'user' = 'UsEr' // false
```